# React state late update

Tags: reactjs

i need to develop a simple tagging system. I do the following:
- on img click I store the click position
- next I open an input text
- on input change I query db with axios
- and so on till the db insert with the tags info

The problem is that the state that I update seems to be 1 turn in the past

```
    imgSetTag(event){

        this.getTagPosition(event)
            .then( (response) => {              
                this.setState({
                    'imgTagsCoord' : response
                }, console.log( 'imgTagsCoord then', this.state.imgTagsCoord ));  

                document.getElementById("imgTagInput").focus();

            })
            .catch( (err) => console.log(err) )

    };

    getTagPosition(event){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var bounds = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - bounds.left;
            var y = event.clientY - bounds.top;
            console.log( {x: x, y: y} );

            var tagCoord = { x : Math.round( x/bounds.width * 100 ), y : Math.round( y/bounds.height * 100 ) };

            resolve(tagCoord);

        });


    }
```

The last try is splitting the function in two and wrapping the second in a promise but this.state.imgTagsCoord is always i round in the past.

Comment: try this.setState({imgTagsCoord : response}); console.log( 'imgTagsCoord then', this.state.imgTagsCoord); document.getElementById("imgTagInput").focus(); instead of everything together

Comment: Thank you, in my first try every piece of istructions was separated, I've putted all together to test the state in the steState callback. Neither of the two solutions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `setState` function should be a [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). In your case, it should be written as follows:

```
() => console.log('imgTagsCoord then', this.state.imgTagsCoord )
```

When you pass in `console.log('imgTagsCoord then', this.state.imgTagsCoord )` directly (instead of wrapping it in an anonymous function), you are passing the *result* of the function instead of the function itself. Therefore, you get the state value at the time when the function executes, which is one round prior to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your setState to this:

```
 this.setState({'imgTagsCoord' : response}, () => console.log( 'imgTagsCoord then', this.state.imgTagsCoord ));
```

You're executing the setState callback directly, you're not giving a function that React will call once the state has been set, but you're logging directly. 
The setState callback is a function that React will execute, in your code you're giving the result of the console.log execution